# how to use OpenMP library in xcode 5.1?

Tags: macos, xcode5, openmp

I want to use openMP library in my project but it seems as if there is no option for openMP in xcode 5.1. if someone knows then please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OpenMP is not a library but a language extension to C, C++ and Fortran. It requires support built into the compiler. Xcode uses compilers based on the LLVM infrastructure. It used to provide two different compiler front-ends - Clang and GCC. Of those two, the former does not have support for OpenMP (yet). The GCC front-end provided some support for old OpenMP features but is no longer part of Xcode. It used to be based on a very old GCC version (4.2.1) and not actively updated since Apple started throwing all their resources into improving Clang.

In other words - no OpenMP support in Xcode 5.1. You can [build your own modern (but non-LLVM) GCC from source](http://solarianprogrammer.com/2013/06/11/compiling-gcc-mac-os-x/) and use it on the command line, but it's hard to integrate it with Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

There is clang with OpenMP 3.1/4.0 support (though not official). You can take it here http://clang-omp.github.io/